# Sharepoint Task List with Email Alerts

Tags: alert

I’m trying to create a task list within sharepoint to manage tasks and deadlines for a larger team. Is there a way to set up an email alert system on a task list in sharepoint, that would send you an alert for the upcoming weeks deadlines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality isn't built in to SharePoint, I'm afraid. Related questions:

["Send email when ownership is assigned?" Due Date functionality](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/65056/send-email-when-ownership-is-assigned-due-date-functionality)

[adding alert on a Date Field](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/78222/adding-aler-on-a-date-field)

The second question has mention of a timer job solution.

Unfortunately I have to mention the two products my company sells that provide this functionality. If you don't want to see third party solutions then look away now. Stop reading. Stop! Too late:

**On-premise:** [Reminder](http://www.pentalogic.net/sharepoint-products/reminder)

**Office 365:** [Reminder 365](http://sharepoint-alert.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Email alerts are possible on mostly all Lists / Libraries. Provided you have configured outgoing email settings on the farm.

Also check this link: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Enable-email-notifications-390a927c